# get groups of "x" number of words in text

Tags: python, string

let's say I have a string

```
s = 'Hello world, I am Foo. I like dogs'
```

I want to parse thru this string and extract words in groups of `x`. Let's say `x = 3`, my output should be:

```
out = ['Hello world, I', 'world, I am', 'I am Foo.', 'am Foo. I', 'Foo. I like', 'I like dogs']
```

Is there a way to do this? I tried this code but it's very bad.

```
    sss = s.split()
    x = 3
    for i, word in enumerate(sss):
        for j in range(x):
            extract = sss[j+i:x+j]
            print(extract)

out: ['Hello', 'world,', 'I']
['world,', 'I', 'am']
['I', 'am', 'Foo.']
['world,', 'I']
['I', 'am']
['am', 'Foo.']
['I']
['am']
['Foo.']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
s = 'Hello world, I am Foo. I like dogs'

words = s.split()
x = 3
results = [
    ' '.join(words[i:i + x])
    for i in range(len(words) - x + 1)
]
print(results)
```

output:

```
['Hello world, I', 'world, I am', 'I am Foo.', 'am Foo. I', 'Foo. I like', 'I like dogs']
```